# MySQL select a row from a daterange excluding the year

Tags: mysql, date-range

I'm trying to create a MySQL query to select the daily price from a table that is between a date range from another. I only want to use 'starting-ending' months and days from the table "seasons" and I want to pass the year dynamically to the query.

This is my query: (I'm giving it the Year to exclude the one on the table)

```
SELECT a.season, b.base_price 
FROM seasons a 
JOIN pricebyseason b ON a.id=b.season_id 
WHERE b.prop_id='6' AND '2015-11-29' BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(a.starting,'2015-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(a.ending,'2016-%m-%d') 
ORDER BY b.base_price DESC
```

It works but not with all dates.

These are the tables:

**seasons** (these are static date values)

```
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
| id |    season    |  starting  | ending     |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Peak Season  | 2015-12-11 | 2016-01-09 |
|  2 | High Season  | 2015-11-27 | 2016-04-15 |
|  3 | Mid Season   | 2015-04-16 | 2015-09-01 |
|  4 | Low Season   | 2015-09-02 | 2015-11-26 |
|  5 | Spring Break | 2015-03-05 | 2015-03-21 |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
```

---

**pricebyseason**

```
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
| id | prop_id | season_id | base_price |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |       6 |         1 |        950 |
|  2 |       6 |         2 |        750 |
|  3 |       6 |         3 |        450 |
|  4 |       6 |         4 |        400 |
|  5 |       6 |         5 |        760 |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+
```

What I want to achive is query the dialy price between checkin, checkout selection
I create this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a6f4

This is a previuos query that is not working either:

```
SELECT a.base_price,b.season,b.starting,b.ending
FROM pricebyseason a JOIN seasons b ON a.season_id=b.id
WHERE a.prop_id='6' AND
(DATE_FORMAT(b.starting,'%m-%d') <= '12-27' OR DATE_FORMAT(b.starting,'2016-%m-%d') >= '2015-12-27')
AND
(DATE_FORMAT(b.ending,'%m-%d') >= '12-27' OR DATE_FORMAT(b.ending,'2016-%m-%d') <= '2015-12-27')
ORDER BY base_price DESC
```

And here are some sample dates for each season: '2016-01-08','2015-12-27','2016-04-14','2015-11-29','2016-04-15','2015-09-01','2016-09-02','2015-11-26','2016-10-10','2016-03-18','2016-06-22','2015-06-15'

Thank a lot

Comment: Can you give us an example for a date which does not work and which result you get?

Comment: Thanks for formating the Tables Barmas ;)

Comment: the date 2015-10-10 wich is located in the lowseason range works if I set the query like DATE_FORMAT(a.starting,'2015-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(a.ending,'2015-%m-%d')

Comment: If `starting` is earlier in the year than `ending`, and you then add 1 to the ending year, all dates after `starting` will match it.

Comment: You need to use different logic depending on whether the starting date is earlier or later in the year than the ending date.

Comment: I know I just can't figure out how. I have this previous query: SELECT a.base_price,b.season,b.starting,b.ending FROM pricebyseason a JOIN seasons b ON a.season_id=b.id WHERE a.prop_id='6' AND (DATE_FORMAT(b.starting,'%m-%d') <= '11-29' OR DATE_FORMAT(b.starting,'2016-%m-%d') >= '2015-11-29') AND (DATE_FORMAT(b.ending,'%m-%d') >= '11-29' OR DATE_FORMAT(b.ending,'2016-%m-%d') <= '2015-11-29') ORDER BY base_price DESC LIMIT 1